# Time complexity for functions within if condition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity for these kind of if statements?

Consider the following time complexities : func1 = O(n) and func2 = O(n)

```
if(func1())
{
   return func2();
}
```

Will the time complexity be O(n^2) or just O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

It will be O(n) because `O(n)+O(n) = 2 O(n)= O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is not run in a loop (As in this statement is executed a single time) the complexity is O(n) + O(n) =  2O(n) = O(n) amortised

Comment: Getting rid of the factor.

Comment: Usually, this has a very different meaning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis.

Answer (score 0):

So here are the steps:
1) func1 gets executed and returns
2) func2 possibly gets executed and returns

As you can see, each function returns before the other one starts, meaning that the time is added. When calculating O, you drop all the times that get added together except the largest one, which is O(n).

As a counter example, a way to get O(n^2) would be
func1(func2)
where func1 executes its argument approximately n times. That means that the time is multiplied.